# How do I package a Springboot application to function as a operating dependency in another Springboot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a Springboot application that has a @Scheduled method. I'd like to package this in a way where other applications that want my functionality can simply add it to their POM and automatically have the @Scheduled method running without making any code changes (excepting configurations).

Is this possible through Springboot? I'd prefer to not create a parent project and rather have it as a dependency. Thanks!

EDIT: I've exported my Springboot application as a Jar and imported it locally but the @Scheduled method never runs.

Comment: 1. you can export a jar out of your spring boot application 2. need some repository manager if you dont want the jar to be publicly available or use central maven repository. 3. use it anywhere else as a dependency

Comment: Ive tried that and the @Scheduled job doesn't run at all.

Comment: Does the project which is using this dependency enable the scheduling in its configuration ?

Comment: I'd prefer not to add any annotations to the consuming project but if there's an application.properties configuration change I can make, please let me know.

EDIT: And I have tried adding the @EnableScheduling in the Application class but there's no change.

Comment: IMO, it should be "consuming" project responsability to decide if it enables scheduling or not. Your dependency should not override existing configuration. It would really chaotic in a project with many dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your own library, just create a separate standard java maven project and put your common classes in it. Make sure **not** to put classes with the @SpringBootApplication in it (Sure it is possible to do that but let's keep it like this for the sake of simplicity).

Your pom should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.my.own</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-own-utils</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>my-own-utils</name>
  <description>My Own Spring Boot App Utilities</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- here you put your dependencies just as in a spring boot app. You can even use starters. -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.301</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Note that this pom **do not use the spring-boot-maven-plugin**, so it will be built as a standard jar.

Next, to use it in an spring boot application, just add it as a normal dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.my.own</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-own-utils</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, to make your spring boot application to process the annotations used in your library, you must use the `@ComponentScan` annotation in your application's Main class so it also search classes in your library packages:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.my.own")
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

At this point, at startup your spring application will look up for beans and components of its own package, plus the `com.my.own` package, over the complete classpath including your library, and instantiate them according to their annotations.

If you want to have control over what should your app instantiate (let's say your library have 5 @Component classes but you just want to use one), you can make use of the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation.

Comment: It was the maven plugin! Taking it out and executing `mvn package` created a jar that was usable for my project